# Not a directory error when try to modify ~/.local/share/applications/

Tags: launcher

I want to add a working eclipse icon to the launcher but when I try to create a file "eclipse.desktop" under ~/.local/share/applications/ I get an error indicating that applications is not a directory.
What may the reason be?
Regards...

Scrrenshot : [image: http://i.imgur.com/33ooh.png]

Comment: Terminal application

Comment: myuser@myusercomp:~$ cd /home/myuser/.local/share/applications
bash: cd: /home/myuser/.local/share/applications: Not a directory

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory `applications': File exists

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `~/.local/share/applications` should be directory(folder) not a file. In your screen shot it is a file. so delete that file, create a folder with same name and then try again.

In terminal

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide very little information, but my guess is that you tried to do it as root. Don't use sudo when you do that, as root doesn't have that folder, and it wouldn't be of use to you anyway.

$HOME/.local/share/applications is supposed to be a directory. If some application uses it for anything else, then that's a bug. Just delete the file and create a directory by the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but no, not as root

Comment: Please edit your question to say what you did, then. That should indeed be a directory.

Comment: Added a screenshot